# Change Line high of chords in Leedsheets package

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, setspace, songs, leadsheets

I am using the Leedsheets package to create a custom Songbook. I changed every font to `\ttfamily` and for the verse-like-environments i determined the size by `\large`. Now the spacing between lines is incredibly high and stretches my whole document dramatically.

I tried to reduce the line height with:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.7}
```

and it works only for text without chords. Beside of that, i already tried to change it with other options mentioned in the [Overleaf Spacing Documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX) but this didn't work either.

I think, that these spacing methods may not work, because the chords aren't actually a line, but just places above the text. Though knowing that, i couldn't figure out, how to make the line high smaller.

Here is a small complete example, you can use to reproduce my issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{leadsheet}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.7}
\setleadsheets{
    verse/numbered=true,
    align-chords = {l},
    remember-chords = true,
    text-format = {\ttfamily\large},
    chorus/format= ,
    info/format= ,
    bar-shortcuts = false 
}
\setchords{
    format = {\ttfamily}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{song}{title={Ye Yacobites by Name}, capo={1}}

\begin{verse}
^{Em}What's right and what is wrang, by the ^{G}law, by the ^{D}law, \\
^{Em}What's right and what is wrang, ^{D}by the ^{Em}law. \\
^{G}What's right and what is wrang, ^{D}the short sword and the lang, \\
^{Em}A weak arm and a strang, for to ^{G}draw, for to ^{D}draw, \\
^{Em}A weak arm and a strang, ^{D}for to ^{Em}draw. \\
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
What makes heroic strife, famed afar? famed afar? \\
What makes heroic strife, famed afar? \\
What makes heroic strife, to whet the assasins knife, \\
Or haunt a parent's life, wi' bloody war? bloody war? \\
Or haunt a parent's life, wi' bloody war? \\
\end{verse}

\end{song}
\end{document}
```

Here is a picture with my Problem:
[image: Problem showcased in a song]

I am really frustrated by now and hope, somebody can help me. Please ask, if you need more info about something.

Thank you very much!

elMuscle

Comment: provide a small but complete example so that one can test your issue. Only screenshots and vage descriptions of your code are not enough.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

leadsheets internally resets the linespread to 1. So if you really want the lines so near to each other better set the size and baselineskip manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{leadsheet}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\setstretch{0.7}
\setleadsheets{
    verse/numbered=true,
    align-chords = {l},
    remember-chords = true,
    text-format = {\fontsize{14pt}{15pt}\ttfamily},  % second dimension should be larger than the first!  
    info/format= ,
    bar-shortcuts = false ,    
}
\setchords{
    format = {\ttfamily}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{song}{title={Ye Yacobites by Name}, capo={1}}

\begin{verse}
^{Em}What's right and what is wrang, by the ^{G}law, by the ^{D}law, \\
^{Em}What's right and what is wrang, ^{D}by the ^{Em}law. \\
^{G}What's right and what is wrang, ^{D}the short sword and the lang, \\
^{Em}A weak arm and a strang, for to ^{G}draw, for to ^{D}draw, \\
^{Em}A weak arm and a strang, ^{D}for to ^{Em}draw. \\
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
What makes heroic strife, famed afar? famed afar? \\
What makes heroic strife, famed afar? \\
What makes heroic strife, to whet the assasins knife, \\
Or haunt a parent's life, wi' bloody war? bloody war? \\
Or haunt a parent's life, wi' bloody war? \\
\end{verse}

\end{song}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your really made my day :)